# Interrupts in C

Tags: c, microcontroller, fpga

I have a question about interrupts in C.

Information:
I use the DE0 Board from Altera, which works with NIOS II and have coded in C.

Actual code description:

I have a `main()` where I have a `while(1)` loop. I coded a Automaton with a Switch-Case construct and my own `typedef` for the states.

Now to my question:

- In each case, I have a various event. For example I call methods or control some LED's.

I want to outsource the events in the Switch-Case construct into an Interrupt Service Routine (ISR).

I can cause state changes, which the ISR will catch, by pressing Button 1 and/or Button 2.

My Problem:
How does the ISR know which case corresponds to which event?

Is it possibile to write different ISR's for each Buttons?

Would this code accomplish this:

```
void alt_irq_register(irNr, (void *) contextPtr, (void *) devPtr);
```

Comment: 1. A code description doesn't jelp fixing a bug, since it could be anywhere in the code but we don't know where because we can't see the code. 2. What does c# have to do with a programming language ... Oh! sorry I mean What does c# have to do with c?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have a choice of two methods. a) input port changes trigger an interrupt, and the ISR feeds the changes and/or states to (say) `main`. b) you have a regular "heartbeat" timer interrupt which polls the button inputs, again reporting change/state to a higher level function. In both cases that could be done by setting variable(s) but could also be done with callback functions.

Comment: Is your C-runtime capable of handling hardware irq's? This requires a context switch from normal program flow to the ISR and back.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whatever information you have given,

You can make your state variable Global and make sure to make it `volatile` as you will be modifying it from ISRs.

```
void ISR_Func()
{
    Read which button is pressed
    Assign value to state variable
}

void main()
{
   while(1)
   {
      switch(state_variable)
        {
           case Button_1:
               button1_func();
           break;
           case Button_2:
               button2_func();
           break;
           default:
           break;

        }


   }

}
```

> My Problem: How the ISR knows in witch Case it is and do the
>   corresponding event?

It is not advised to execute state machine functionality from ISR. It is better to modify state from ISR and execute functionality from existing state machine.

> Is there a possibility to write diffrent ISR's for 2 Buttons?

As you have not mentioned how those buttons are connected, You can connect two buttons to 2 different "External Hardware Interrupt" pins and you can write one ISR for each external hardware interrupt.